# recursively adding files in perforce with python

Tags: python

I'm building a python script that is supposed to recursively add files from 3 subdirs in perforce and submit them. Here's how it looks:

```
wksp = "myworkspace"


subprocess.Popen("dir /b /s /a-d | p4 -c " + wksp + " -x - add")
```

here is the error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "v2_PEP8.py", line 286, in <module>
    p4()
  File "v2_PEP8.py", line 226, in p4
    subprocess.Popen("dir /b /s /a-d | p4 -c " + wksp + " -x - add")
  File "C:\Programs\python\App\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Programs\python\App\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

If I print out the entire command and paste it into the command line it works, but for some reason when the script executes it via subprocess.Popen it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `subprocess.Popen` expects to invoke a *process*.  There is no `dir` executable; it's a command that's internally recognized by the `cmd.exe` shell.

`subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe /c dir /s /a-d")` instead should work, but you'd probably need to capture the output and redirect it yourself.

You also could try `os.system("dir /b /s /a-d | p4 -c " + wksp + " -x - add")`, which should invoke the entire command in the system shell.

(Of course, since you're using Python, you don't need to use `dir` to get a list of files; you instead could use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) or [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).)